# Are these two different groups that are being referred to in Numbers 14:22-23?

Tags: referent-identification, numbers, moses

Numbers 14:22-23 (KJV)

> 22 Because ***all those men*** which have seen my glory, and my miracles, which I did in Egypt and in the wilderness, and have tempted me now these ten times, and have not hearkened to my voice;  23 Surely they shall not see the land which I sware unto their fathers, ***neither shall any of them*** that provoked me see it:

In the above text its not clear whether the people mentioned here its a single group or two groups that are being referred to.

There are two terms used here ***TEMPTED*** and ***PROVOKED*** which is not clear whether this reference is to one group or two?

Comment: Those that died included 10 who did see the land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire chapter context would suggest that this is one group. All the chapter verses prior to 22-23 talk of "the company" or "the people"; ie one group.

Note verse 15:

> 15 Now if thou shalt kill all this people as one man, then the nations
>   which have heard the fame of thee will speak, saying,

Young's Literal Translation helps in seeing that this is just one group, ie YLT does not use the word "neither" in verse 23.

> 22 for all the men who are seeing My honour, and My signs, which I
>   have done in Egypt, and in the wilderness, and try Me these ten times,
>   and have not hearkened to My voice --
>
> 23 they see not the land which I have sworn to their fathers, yea,
>   none of those despising Me see it;

Also, other scripture tells us the the "provocation" is the same as the temptation in the wilderness.

Psalm 95:8

> Harden not your heart, as in the provocation, and as in the day of
>   temptation in the wilderness:

Hebrews 3:8

> Harden not your hearts, as in the provocation, in the day of
>   temptation in the wilderness: